# ionic build error - cordova-file plugin issue

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I am having trouble - creating an android build using ionic. It was initially working fine. I tried changing the android target platform to 19 - thats 4.4.2 kitkat.

this is the error message- apparently there is an issue with the **cordova file plugin.** **When I change the platform sdk target to 19**.

Any help will be appreciated here.

/myapp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/LocalFilesystem.java:414: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/myapp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/LocalFilesystem.java:416: error: cannot find symbol
            for (File f : context.getExternalMediaDirs()) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getExternalMediaDirs()
  location: variable context of type Context
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just remove and add the android platform back. And then its smooth sailing.